# How to to display different options on navbar depending on what the user inputs?

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering if it is possible to show different input fields depending on what the user selects? For example, I want for a user to be able to select the number of factors they are using for their study, and then, depending on that number, be able to create factor labels for each, and then be able to input different means and standard deviations for each factor.

So basically, have input that dynamically changes after selecting number of factors, where the option to label them pops up after, and then boxes to input means and standard deviations come up. Hope it isn't confusing.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There are patterns for updating UI dynamically in the documentation, see: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html I recommend that you come back when you have a minimum working example that we can help you with.